# Split content of field into 2 fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have to run a query in Access sql or using the Query Wizard to split the data of field into 2.

The field has data such as `1234 ave willie` and has email addresses such as `haha@yahoo.com` .

I need to put `1234 ave willie` in a new field named *St address* and `haha@yahoo.com` in *Email*.

Can someone help? Is there a wildcard operator like `LIKE` etc?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using `LIKE` to determine which field is an email and which field is an address.  Something like this would work:

```
SELECT Field, 'Email' FieldType
FROM YourTable
WHERE Field Like '*@*'
UNION ALL
SELECT Field, 'Address' FieldType
FROM YourTable
WHERE Field Not Like '*@*'
```

You mention you need to split these in 2 separate fields -- depends on the table structure.  But assuming you add 2 new fields to the original table, then something like this should work:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET Email = Field WHERE Field Like '*@*'
UPDATE YourTable SET Address = Field WHERE Field Not Like '*@*'
```

You can find a better algorithm to search by email address -- this is just an example.  But assuming any field with an @ symbol is an email, then the above will work fine.  Here's an SO post with SQL Email validation that can help get you started:

[Sql script to find invalid email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801166/sql-script-to-find-invalid-email-addresses)

Comment: My understanding of OP's situation that both Street Address and E-mail Address will appear in the **same** field.  Thus a need to **split**.

Comment: @PM77-1 -- My understanding was the field stored either the address or the email -- I could have been mistaken.  Need further explanation from OP to fully understand.

Comment: Exactly that field has either a street adress or an email adress.So i need to display email in a field and street adress in another field

Comment: I need to use this in access...

Comment: I think i need to use instr() and substr()

Comment: non of the above works..

Comment: We are very close...
again il explain..
I have a field called contact it has either email adress or street adreeses.
When i run my query i need to tell it put all email address in 1 other field called email and all the street address in another field name address.
So the contact field has either an email or street addrees?

Comment: data are as follows in table:

CustomerName    Contact
Rico             34 mills ave
James            bb@yahoo.com
Dav              567 rick avenue 
Dav              567 rick avenue 


I need query like this:

Customer Name     Email          Address
Rico                             34 mills ave
James            bb@yahoo.com

Comment: CustomerName                 Contact
Rico                         34 mills ave
James                        bb@yahoo.com
Dav                          567 rick avenue 
I need query like this:


Customer Name                Email                         Address
Rico                                                     34 mills ave

James                      bb@yahoo.com

Dav                                                      567 rick avenue