# Issue with Email address validation in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM people 
WHERE email NOT LIKE '%_@__%.__%'
```

referred from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801166/sql-script-to-find-invalid-email-addresses) to validate the email address.

The query is working fine in all scenarios except when the `email` is invalid due to a space.
For example, the query is failing for the following  invalid `email` address value.
  @   .

Can we find the column with space using a `Like` statement?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: There's usually a more appropriate layer at which to do email validation than in the database. And using pattern matching (whether simple or regex) for email validation is generally flawed. Accept anything with an `@` and if you want any more assurance, the only way to be sure the email address is valid is to attempt to use it.

Comment: I am using Sql server 2012

Comment: So, the `mysql`, `sqlite` and `sql-server-2008` tags were *all* wrongly applied then?

Answer (score 0):

Email validation is a hairy exercise at best. At a minimum, I'd validate in a [stored procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx#sql:stored_procedure) written in a 3rd language. As your [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801166/sql-script-to-find-invalid-email-addresses) notes:

> Validating e-mail addresses in code is virtually impossible.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM people 
WHERE email NOT LIKE '%_@__%.__%'  query is working fine in almost all cases except when a space is present. I am thinking if I can validate space  then I will use multiple queries to validate email address, which will cover almost all scenarios.

Comment: why don't you use `trim` then later apply your query ?

Comment: I need to check whether the column has any space. Trim will not serve the purpose.

Comment: This should really be a comment, on nth thought. Sorry about that, users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LEN()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) function and [Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) functions:

```
Select
  Id,
  Email
From
  MyTable
Where
  LEN(Email) <> LEN(REPLACE(Email,' ', ''))
```

See the [SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/14e43/1)