# Create custom advance search filter in CGridView in YII

Tags: yii, cgridview

I have a model which contains emails with some other fields.
I want a custom filter in Yii `CGridView`'s advance search which when applied, lists only Invalid Email IDs (using regular expression `'^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$'`)

*Note: I dont want to add any column in CGridView*

Comment: That's not the regex for valid email adresses; that would look more like `(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_}\`{|}~-]+)*|”(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*”)@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])`; but actually is way [more complicated](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

Comment: Thanks for your correction, But can you please tell me the answer of my real problem

Comment: Sorry, I'm no Yii expert, just wanted to point out that email addresses usually are not uppercase alphanumerical...; I would have written an answer if I had one.
However, your question is not really well-written. Maybe add what you've already tried, why the official documentation has failed you, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help you out,

you will need several things

1. the line for filtering in the column of your choice...(i recommend you create a new attribute for this, ask me in comments if you want to know more why.) this goes in the cgridview of course:

   'filter'=>CHtml::activeCheckBox($model, $attributeEmail)
2. the condition in your search of function that brings up the model.

Supposing you have a criteria inside your search in your model wich help you with your filtering what you need is ...

```
if($this->EMAIL == TRUE)
{
    $criteria->addCondition("\"t\".\"EMAIL\" email NOT LIKE '%_@__%.__%'");
}
```

Why not to use regex and make a KISS approach ? better read this first...

[Sql script to find invalid email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801166/sql-script-to-find-invalid-email-addresses)

I'd be glad to hear your comments it is interesting question for yii dev's btw