# Update regex to also allow blank string/response

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a regex here that validates emails:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$
```

Can this regex be updated to allow a blank string (no email)?

I tried adding ^$ | into the regex but that basically just broke the whole regex and allows any string to be used.

Comment: Take a peek at the selected answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801166/sql-script-to-find-invalid-email-addresses

Comment: You know SQL Server has no support for regex?

Comment: No support for Internationalized Domain Names?

Comment: Don't validate emails with a regex. Ever.

Comment: Do not ever add `^$|`, this is a bad way to do it. Simply `^abc$` -> `^(abc)?$`, make the pattern in between the anchors optional.

Comment: I think validating emails with long regexes is a fools errand, just make sure the email looks reasonably ok (contains `@` and something on both sides of it) and move on, just because it's valid or whatever doesn't mean email can be sent later anyway

Comment: @DaleK - Not **yet** anyway https://twitter.com/AzureSQL/status/1770743788027175100?s=20