# SQL table column with email address

Tags: sql

I have a table ‘customers’ with two columns 'email' and ‘value’.  The ‘email’ column contains email addresses and ‘value’ column contains NULL values.  Now I would like to write an Update command, so that if an email is in right format (a@b.c) then SET the ‘value’ column with ‘True’ and if the email address is in wrong format (a.b.c  Or @b.c) then SET the ‘value’ column with ‘False’. Now my question is how I shall write the SQL command to find out which email address is right. Any suggestion please.  Thanks.

Comment: Please read [this write-up](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) before you make your decision about doing this.  There are significant trade-offs you need to consider, for example the fact that a syntactically-valid email address may still not be deliverable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or newer I would recommend creating a CLR function that checks for the validity of your emails.  Take a look at this article to understand how this is done:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Once you have a function find a regex for your email address (attempt below) and use an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE Customers
SET Value = dbo.RegexMatch( email , N'^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$' )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQL-Server this example (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423606/t-sql-checking-for-email-format)) could help you.

```
IF (
     CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address))) = 0 
AND  LEFT(LTRIM(@email_address),1) <> '@' 
AND  RIGHT(RTRIM(@email_address),1) <> '.' 
AND  CHARINDEX('.',@email_address ,CHARINDEX('@',@email_address)) - CHARINDEX('@',@email_address ) > 1 
AND  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address ))) - LEN(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address)),'@','')) = 1 
AND  CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address)))) >= 3 
AND  (CHARINDEX('.@',@email_address ) = 0 AND CHARINDEX('..',@email_address ) = 0)
)
   print 'valid email address'
ELSE
   print 'not valid'
```

I think that changing `print` code with an `UPDATE...` will do your job.

Comment: @Abe Miessler: you're absolutely right! I deleted that part... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

the code to determine that is much better off the SQL side, write that in whichever language you're using to get those email addresses, then just perform the update using a simple query

Comment: If the DBMS has decent RegEx support can't see any benefit to this.

Answer (score 0):

you'll be a lot better off doing that in the front end, and passing the validation result to the database along with the email.  This seems like a good case for a regex match.

Answer (score 0):

> find out which email address is right

While you can to **validate** in the database values that fail to fits the correct pattern for an email address, the database cannot **verify** whether an email address can be used to contact its intended recipient (the Closed World Assumption applies).

Support for pattern matching varies between SQL implementations. For example, SQL Server has `LIKE` for simplistic pattern matching. Best to write multiple tests for specific failures: does not contain exactly one `@` symbol, has no domain, is too long, contains a character other than those allowed, etc. By giving each test a unique constraint name, more granular error  messages can be conveyed to the user.