# Email validation in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to verify the email is valid or not?

For example:

- `test@test.com` - valid
- `test@@.com` - invalid
- `test@.com` - invalid

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423606/t-sql-checking-for-email-format

Comment: I don't think there's a foolproof way of doing this, except to send to it and see if you get an error. Even if you are able to detect if an address is syntactically valid, you can't tell whether the email address exists or whether sending will succeed unless you try it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of creating a table with specific rules for mail with address (regexp). Then an example with sql query pattern (Regexp). With this you should be able to do what you want

***Create table with regexp***

```
create table Contacts (
FirstName nvarchar(30),
LastName nvarchar(30),
EmailAddress nvarchar(30) CHECK (dbo.RegExMatch('[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.)+(com|org|edu|nz)', EmailAddress)=1),
USPhoneNo nvarchar(30) CHECK (dbo.RegExMatch('\([1-9][0-9][0-9]\) [0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', UsPhoneNo)=1))
INSERT INTO [talend].[dbo].[Contacts]
([FirstName]
,[LastName]
,[EmailAddress]
,[USPhoneNo])
VALUES
('Hallam'
,'Amine'
,'mhallam@talend.com’
,'0129-2090-1092')
,( 'encoremoi'
,'nimportequoi'
,'amine@zichji.org'
,'(122) 190-9090')
GO
```

***Execute request sql with regexp***

```
SELECT [FirstName]
,[LastName]
,[EmailAddress]
,[USPhoneNo]
FROM [talend].[dbo].[Contacts]
where [talend].[dbo].RegExMatch([EmailAddress],'[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.)+(com|org|edu|nz|au)') = 1
```

***Function Code***

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public partial class RegExBase
{
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
public static int RegExMatch( string matchString , string pattern)
{
Regex r1 = new Regex(pattern.TrimEnd(null));
if (r1.Match(matchString.TrimEnd(null)).Success == true)
{
return 1 ;
}
else
{
return 0 ;
}
}
};
```

For more explication show here ths tutorial -> http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CGkQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.talendforge.org%2Fbugs%2Ffile_download.php%3Ffile_id%3D4729%26type%3Dbug&ei=f8C9UKTMBNSN4gTo0IHYDg&usg=AFQjCNG-ezRtC9TdcJXuXGl4T8KX4zbUww&sig2=Fpgm5UTYOK4dpsaMfNCCyQ&cad=rja

I hope this help you

Comment: Thanks for reply.. this my test data   test@test.com  valid
'test@test.com   valid
test@test.com  valid
t'est@test.com  valid   hwo to validate it
test@test.c   invalid
@test.com   invalid
test@    invalid
test@@test.com  invalid
test@test..com  invalid
test@test.  invalid
test.com  invalid
test@test@test.com  invalid

Comment: There are two possible! My example comes from a given solution linking a program in c # with sql server.Please show this link http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CGkQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.talendforge.org%2Fbugs%2Ffile_download.php%3Ffile_id%3D4729%26type%3Dbug&ei=f8C9UKTMBNSN4gTo0IHYDg&usg=AFQjCNG-ezRtC9TdcJXuXGl4T8KX4zbUww&sig2=Fpgm5UTYOK4dpsaMfNCCyQ&cad=rja If you do not use program in visual studio. You can directly write the function in SQL SERVER. Creating a new stored procedure . A can like this: CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RegExMatch] ........:

Comment: More informations about this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx  Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

There is one newer efficient way to do that is to extend .Net functionality for SQL.

Please check details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

One ready source code for regex match is at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server-2005-2008.

Now a simple regex for Email should do the magic for you
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks,can we do it sql server function in DB

Comment: @muralikrishna: Check the code at both the links provided.You write regex matching C# code and then call that function in SQL.

Comment: Thank lot i will try let you know

Answer (score 1):

Some years back I wrote  a program about [Pattern Matching – Email Validation](http://pewned123.wordpress.com/tag/sql-email-validation/). Hope that may help you.