# String Building in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, parsing, csv, sp-send-dbmail, string-building

According to the [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) `sp_send_dbmail` must be a semicolon delimited list. However, in many of my applications I am unable to guarantee that this list will be clean. I need a robust way for ensuring a **syntactically valid** list of emails such that my applications will not break if it isn't.

I've been looking into `XML PATH`, `STUFF`, and other methods, but the syntax is hideously confusing. Does anyone have a handy method in their bag of tricks (no stored procedures or functions please, I'd like an out-of-the-box solution)?

Conceptually I thought it best to part the CSV list into a temp table, handle each email separately, then recompose the list using a semicolon delimiter instead. I suspect there is a better method though.

Again, I would like an **out-of-the-box solution** if at all possible. :)

Comment: Will this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423606/t-sql-checking-for-email-format) work for you?