# Makes preg_grep keep and not reorder the arrays keys after each execution

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, preg-grep

I'm trying to clean my email database that was imported from an excel table. So there's plenty of bad characters, and even two or three emails in the same cell. I dont want to use a direct database solution as was posted here ([T-SQL: checking for email format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423606/t-sql-checking-for-email-format)), because I will do a double check by eye before actually excluding it.

1) First I got all of those emails that weren't good shaped. Then I transformed them on to an array. Note that I'm in laravel ecosystem.

```
$contato = DB::select("select * from emailstable where outro_email NOT REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'");

$email_array = json_decode(json_encode($email_database_as_object), true);
```

2) From those, I eliminated all those records that do not have the @ symbol on it (empty, null, random phrases), excluding them from the original array:

```
$corretor = preg_grep("/@/i", array_column($email_array, "email"), PREG_GREP_INVERT);

foreach ($corretor as $key => $value) {
         $email_array = array_except($email_array, array($key));
    }
```

But the biggest problem is that when I'm trying to remove the bad characters, the preg_grep assigns to the resulting array, new array keys. Instead of keeping the original ones.

As an exemple:
Original array keys that were filtered: 1,4,10,24,34,65,78 (7 keys)
Assigned keys: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

On my code, I'm trying to extract the multiple emails that was inserted in one cell, through separators as ";" , ",' and " ", using preg_grep:

```
$email_corrected = array(); //array to get all of the corrected emails

$corretor = preg_grep("/;/i", array_column($email_array, "outro_email"));
foreach ($corretor as $key => $value) {
   $provisorio = explode(';', $value);
   $provisorio  = array_where($provisorio, function($chave, $valor)
   {
      return strlen($valor) > 0;
  }); //laravel function to take out empty results of explode
   $provisorio=array_map('trim',$provisorio);
   $email_corrected[$key] = $provisorio; //adds the result to corrected emails
   $email_array = array_except($email_array, array($key)); // takes out the result from the original array
} 


$corretor = preg_grep("/,/i", array_column($email_array, "outro_email"));
foreach ($corretor as $key => $value) {
   $provisorio = explode(',', $value);
   $provisorio  = array_where($provisorio, function($chave, $valor)
   {
      return strlen($valor) > 0;
  });
   $provisorio=array_map('trim',$provisorio);
   $email_corrected[$key] = $provisorio;
   $email_array = array_except($email_array, array($key));
}

$corretor = preg_grep("/\//", array_column($contato_array, "outro_email"));
foreach ($corretor as $key => $value) {
   $provisorio = explode(',', $value);
   $provisorio  = array_where($provisorio, function($chave, $valor)
   {
      return strlen($valor) > 0;
  });
   $provisorio=array_map('trim',$provisorio);
   $email_corrected[$key] = $provisorio;
   $email_array = array_except($email_array, array($key));
}
```

But after each preg_grep, the keys from $corretor does not match the original keys from $email_array. As a result, Im not eliminating the correct keys from the original array when doing $email_array = array_except($email_array, array($key));

Thanks in advance.